# How to add reactions to messages sent by a webhook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to add reactions to a messages sent by a webhook but idk how can I make this, here is my code:

````
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('url', adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
        embed = discord.Embed(color=color)
        caractère = ["(", "'", ")", ","]
        for caractère in caractère:
            args = str(args).replace(caractère, "")
        embed.add_field(name="Nouvelle suggestion !", value=str(args).strip(""))
        embed.set_footer(text=f"""{ctx.message.author} • {datetime.now().strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")}""",
                         icon_url=str(ctx.message.author.avatar_url))
        message = await webhook.send(embed=embed, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it, After sending the Embed i do

```
reactions = "\U0001f44d"
reactions2 = "\U0001f44e"
await application.add_reaction(reactions)
await application.add_reaction(reactions2)
```

application is the name of my embed, you will need to change it to whatever you name yours. 
You could also import emoji and just do :thumbup: or whatever reactions you're after.

Comment: I have an error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'application' is not defined

Comment: You need to change application.add_reaction to the name of your Embed. Yours will be embed.add_reaction.

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Embed' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'